# How to reuse custom functions in different Laravel controllers?

Tags: laravel

I have build several functions that I reuse in almost all of my controllers, at the moment I have to paste every function in every controller in order to work. The code looks really messy and it is quite difficult to make edists as I get lost in the lines.

How or where can I declare my functions so I can reuse them in all controllers witout pasting them there?

Comment: You can make helper functions, or can make one class consisting of functions, then in your controller you can use those class functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own `BaseController` in which you can store the functions that you reuse, and then your controller that needs those function can extend from the `BaseController`.

Another approach is to create a custom helper file, which will contain the functions that you reuse. For example create a `helpers.php` file in the app folder, and then add that in the `composer.json` to autoload.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/helpers.php" // here is the helpers file to autoload.
    ],
        "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
```

After this run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create a service layer and inject into a controller

```
class AnyController {
    public function __construct(MyService $myService)
    {
        $this->myService = $myService;
    }

    public function anyFunction()
    {
        // $this->myService->foo()
    }
}
```

Or you can inject into a particular action

```
class AnyController {
    public function anyFunction(MyService $myService)
    {
        // $this->myService->foo()
    }
}
```

Read more

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container